# I just started learning scala ..would you please tell me what the below statement is trying to say?.. <: sign means ?what is product with seralizable

Tags: scala

```
val queryregistry: seq[Tableinfo[_ <: Product with serializable]] = Seq(science,math,gk)
```

Comment: `A <: B` means `A` is a subtype of `B`; `_` is a wildcard, so an existential type. `Product with Serializable` is a type, both are classes that all case classes extend. - Anyways, just seeing that I would guess who wrote that code didn't know too much about **Scala** neither.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.